# How to limit number of logins at a time?

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Hello I have a website. created using php,mysql. I want to set a limit like.. only 10 user can login my website at same time. How can I do that kind of a setting? any body knows the solution kindly help me..

Comment: Are you sure you really want it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a database table to store the number of logged in users but you need to come up with some way of imposing a time limit on those users. I would suggest a field in the table which notes their last activity. When a new user attempts to login you need to apply some logic like this (pseudocode):

```
if(<10users){
    login
} elseif(any of the users have no activity for 30 mins){
    remove that user and login
} else {
    inform user of no space
}
```

You would need to update the last activity every time a logged in user visits a new page.

Comment: You could also make ajax pings to monitor if user is still on your site (assuming JS would be enabled).

Answer (score 1):

Go read up on sessions in PHP, then write your own session handler - the first time as a learning exercise. Then write your own session handler **again**, fixing all the bugs from your first attempt and adding in the facility to count active sessions.

Note that the normal behaviour for session handlers is that the session data persists even after the session has timed out - its up to the garbage collector (and optionally the session loader) to clear up session data which is stale.

Answer (score 0):

i would override php session handling and store user sessions in the database. you can find a simple tutorial here: http://www.raditha.com/php/session.php

this way you can simply check if there are more than 10 valid sessions stored in your database table. though you have to think about handling logouts and timeouts, as some standard timeout like 30 minutes might not work well in your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 10 user logged on your site, disable the login box if there are more than 10 users logged in.

This presume that you have a table in the db that records the users that are logged in the site. The login procedure will write a new line in the table. The logout procedure will delete it.

Simply count the numbers of rows in this table to determine the number of users.

Comment: And what if users won't log out, but instead just close their browsers. There must be some way to check if user is still on the website or just did not log out.

Comment: Great question: use a session for the user activity. Update it for every operation that the user is doing. (Read: every page load if you don't user ajax). If the difference between the last operation and the current time is greater than your idle timeout, delete the row from the table. Of course the session timeout must be greater than your idle timeout. If you don't want to use session, add another field to the table of logged user, that you update on every action. Use that field to determine the idle time. In this case you are killing the database!

Answer (score 0):

as answered above you have to maintain a table which will store the number of users who logged in,but whenever the user logs out then decrement that value....whenever a new user logins increment that value by checking it with ur limit